# How to track from which page the modal was popped up in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an acknowledgement popup modals on near about 15 html pages which appears on successful form completion. How would I know/track from which page the modal was triggered?﻿
I have added a google tag manager code for popup event of modals which shows the number of count it was popped up. I also read about Virtual page views but not sure if its a correct method to track page wise popups.
Please help.
TIA

Comment: You can already see the information you need, if you look at your event total in GA 
 report you can add url dimension to the report that will tell you on which pages the event fired and how many times.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.